# ProFTPD: Connecting works, file transfer doesn't

Tags: lan, proftpd

In our local network I set up a ProFTPD Server on my RaspPi in order to tell my FTP-enabled Webcam to store it's pictures there. However, I am not able to get it to work.

What I did was installing ProFTPD on it, using the following config:

```
<Global>
    RequireValidShell off
</Global>
# If desired turn off IPv6
UseIPv6 off
# Default directory is ftpusers home
DefaultRoot ~ ftpuser
MasqueradeAddress       192.168.2.108      # the RaspPi's local IP address
PassivePorts 60000 65535
```

I then proceeded to add a new user using

```
adduser webcam --shell /bin/false --home /var/www/webcam
```

I can see based on the `/var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log` that the login from my webcam (and manual ftp 127.0.0.1) succeeds:

```
Feb 05 09:44:12 raspberrypi proftpd[20546] raspberrypi (192.168.2.122[192.168.2.122]): FTP session opened.
Feb 05 09:44:12 raspberrypi proftpd[20546] raspberrypi (192.168.2.122[192.168.2.122]): USER webcam: Login successful.
```

However, my webcam says it can't upload the image, and both the xferlog and commandlog remain empty. My webcam is configured to use 192.168.2.108 as a FTP server, using username and password with PASV mode. I tried using PORT mode as well, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas on what the problem could be? My raspPi isn't even required to be available on the internet, I just need the pictures to be transferred there locally.

Comment: So it looks like they’re both in the same subnet, right? Is there any firewall active on your Pi?

Comment: What does [ProFTPD debug logging, debug level 10](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html) show, after user "webcam" logs in?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the DefaultRoot directive says that the syntax you've used restricts members of the group "ftpuser" to their home directory. Did you really mean to limit this to the group "ftpuser"? If not, you might want to remove that group name restriction from the end of the directive statement.